# Neo4j indexing bug?

Tags: indexing, neo4j

After [asking about Neo4j caches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26525805/how-are-neo4j-caches-speeding-up-queries), without having a definitive solution I kept testing Neo4j as the database that probably we are using in production. However, I am facing now a new problem with indexing attributes with specific labels.

The thing is that somehow, Neo4j is not getting the right data if I request a node by label and attribute (that accidentally have the same name). I've took some screenshots of what is happening hoping that it helps to understand the way I deduced that could be a bug. These are two examples of what is happening with two different labels.:

[image]

I have label **A** and label **B**, and attributes **a** and **b**. If you read from bottom to top, you can see that I am following these steps:

1. I request nodes with attribute **a**  (no label) <- works
2. I request nodes with label **A** and attribute **a** <- **doesn't work** (using index)
3. I request nodes with label **A** and attribute **b** <- works
4. I request nodes with label **B** and attribute **a** <- works
5. I request nodes with label **B** and attribute **b** <- works (using index)

I also added extra columns to my request (they have no influence) to check that both columns have the same value, and also checking the labels.

I am having this issue only if the attribute is indexed using **a label with the same name**. That means, label **A** and attribute **a**. However, this is not happening with label **B** and attribute **b**. Not this time at least, because reproducing same scenario with other label an attribute name (following the rule **A** ... **a**) is causing the same problem.

I don't need to say that there is no influence from outside, so I have full control of what is happening in my database.

**EDIT:**

[image]

Comment: What version are you running? Can you run the consistency checker on your data: http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/01/22/neo4j-backup-store-copy-and-consistency-check/

Answer (score 1):

Your #1 did not really "work", since you should have gotten (at least) 2 rows (one for each label).

In your RETURN statements, you should include `id(n)` so that you can see which nodes are being returned. Right now, it is not clear.

EDITED

OK, with the IDs listed, it is now clear that we are talking about a single node with multiple labels. So, this certainly looks like a weird bug. If you are seeing this in the latest release, you should think about creating an issue for this at github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues.

Comment: If you check the documentation, the function `labels()` returns the collection as a column http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-functions-collection.html#functions-labels . About the id of the node, I am editing the question adding a new screenshot. The other things that you suggested in the last 2 paragraphs were also my first toughs and for that reason I added the two extra columns checking the equality of the columns and also the name of the labels

Comment: OK, with the IDs listed, it is now clear that we are talking about a single node with multiple labels. So, this certainly looks like a weird bug. If you are seeing this in the latest release, you should think about creating an issue for this at https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues.
(I've edited my answer to include this text)